# PromQL: Detect when one metric changes while another does not

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

I have two metrics: `my_bytes_in` and `my_bytes_out`. I want to detect when `my_bytes_in` changed while `my_bytes_out` did not for a couple of minutes. As pseudo code you could say:

```
IF my_bytes_in changed over the last five minutes while my_bytes_out did not 
THEN return 1 
ELSE return 0
```

In PromQL I built this query:

```
((vector(1) and on() (sum(my_bytes_in{project="$Project", stage="$Stage", myname=~"$My_Name"}) - sum(my_bytes_in{project="$Project", stage="$Stage", myname=~"$My_Name"} offset 5m)) != 0 and (sum(my_bytes_out{project="$Project", stage="$Stage", myname=~"$My_Name"}) - sum(my_bytes_out{project="$Project", stage="$Stage", myname=~"$My_Name"} offset 5m)) == 0) or on() vector(0))
```

You could probably use rate() instead of using that offset method but anyway. This works for exactly one variable combination:

[grafana screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAPZz.png)

As soon as I have a multi select on the `$My_Name` variable I still just get one graph. Also because of using `vector()` the labels are missing so maybe I need a very different approach?

Is it possible to get a metric as PromQL result that does this anomaly detection and supports multi selection of variable inputs? Currently I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Do you *need* 0 if condition is false?

Comment: What labels do you want to have in result? All present in source metrics, or only those that are used in selectors?

Comment: @markalex I want to have the labels that are in the source metrics, at least the three mentioned in the query and used for the variables.

0 if condition is false would be nice but maybe I could live without that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood everything but I'll try =)

### changes()

**changes()** function shows number of times its value has changed within the provided time range.

F.e how much changes for metric `my_bytes_in` over last 5 min (omitting labels for simplicity):

```
changes(my_bytes_in{}[5m])
```

### bool

**bool** operator is useful to convert filtering conditions to `1` and `0` (we will use them later for multiplication)

Show `1` for metric `my_bytes_in` if there are changes over last 5 min, show `0` if there no changes:

```
changes(my_bytes_in{}[5m]) > bool 0
```

Show `1` for metric `my_bytes_in` if there are NO changes over last 5 min, show `1` of there are some changes:

```
changes(my_bytes_out{}[5m]) != bool 0
```

### Vector matching

Since you filter by labels `project`, `stage`, `myname`, I suppose you want to match results by all the other labels.

Let's combine all together:

```
(changes(my_bytes_in{project="$Project", stage="$Stage", myname=~"$My_Name"}[5m]) > bool 0) 
  * ignoring (project, stage, myname)
(changes(my_bytes_out{project="$Project", stage="$Stage", myname=~"$My_Name"}[5m]) != bool 0)
```

So the resulting query return `1` only for time series with both conditions returning `1` (`1`*`1`=`1`), and `0` otherwise.

Comment: This does not work. Although there's currently no 5 minute interval where my_bytes_in changed while my_bytes_out did not change I get an up and down graph jumping from 0 to 1 and back. 

Also: If I multiselect myname from the dropdown list of my dashboard I get:
"execution: found duplicate series for the match group {} on the right hand-side of the operation: [{my_name="5100_test"}, {my_name="5200_test"}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side"

Comment: But you got me into the right direction! -->

(sum by(stage, myname) (changes(my_bytes_in{project="$Project", stage="$Stage", myname=~"$My_Name"}[5m])) != 0
and
sum by(stage, myname) (changes(my_bytes_out{project="$Project", stage="$Stage", myname=~"$My_Name"}[5m])) == 0)

--- This reacts indeed as I want it. I just have to convert the whatever found values to 1 and if no value is found then it should be 0.

Comment: @elbino consider using `bool` operator for this

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this seems to work now. :)

Comment: @elbino feel free to improve my answer to make it useful for other SO users